# What are some of the best approaches for variable selection in Poisson regression?

Tags: feature-selection, poisson-regression

My target variable follows a Poisson distribution. I have to make a selection of best variables out of about 2000 variables. Is there any method exist for variable selection for poisson type distribution. So far I am familiar with variable reduction methods like lasso,IV,stepwise,PLS. What are some of the ideas, that I can try for poisson? Will it work good, if I convert the target to log(y) and treat it as linear model for variable selection?

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to forecast? Or do you want to do inferential statistics? In the latter case, *any* way of selection variables based on observations will bias your p-values.

Comment: The objective is login counts prediction for a user in a given month

Answer (score 5):

You can use the lasso or elastic net regularisation. Both are available in `glmnet`, if you are an R user, with a poisson dependent variable, using the `family=poisson` option. Hopefully you have sufficient observations to be able to split the dataset and do cross validation.

Stepwise selection methods are generally best avoided, particularly with 2000 variables.

`log(y)` isn't a good idea if the data are poisson since you will be taking logs of zero. Of course you could use `log(y+1)` but since `glmnet` supports the poisson distribution this doesn't seem necessary unless there are computational limitations.

Comment: and what statistics would tell me the best predictors?

Comment: @user2542275: how to find the best (most important) predictors in Poisson regression is a separate and independent question. Please go ahead and post it as such, using the tags [tag:importance] and [tag:poisson-regression], and including your main target of prediction. Posting a new question is better, because then any answers will be far easier to find for future users than if they are buried in a comment. Thank you!